# How to move gzip files to hdfs

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs, gzip

Im new to hadoop. Have to move files from EDS( enterprise data source) where we have data from external and internal vendors on daily and monthly basis. In eds we have gzip files. How to move to hdfs ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Put command](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put). this command can be used for moving your local data stored in eds to HDFS.

refrasing from documentation:

```
hadoop fs -put localfile /user/hadoop/hadoopfile
hadoop fs -put localfile1 localfile2 /user/hadoop/hadoopdir
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `copyFromLocal` command [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyFromLocal)

Additionally and more importantly, if your gzip files is bigger than your default block size (e.g. 128 MB) I strongly recommend you to put the gzip files using `-Ddfs.block.size` parameter setting to your average gzip file size.

Gzip files created outside of hadoop (unless you create a sequencefile inside the hadoop) cannot be worked on splitted blocks during a map-reduce job. So this situation yields to your gzip files splitted throughout the cluster losing locality and when a job starts on any gzip file, all the blocks have to be merged into a file, creating a bottleneck on network.

This parameter will not split OR will split your gzip files into much less number of blocks than it would be.
For example; 2 GB of gzip file will be split into 16 blocks in case of 128 MB block size. If your block size of put is 1 GB, it is only 2 blocks to be merged.

The parameter usage: `hadoop fs -Ddfs.block.size=1G -copyFromLocal localfile /user/root/destination`